# Why does int (*j)[2] = my_array give warning?

Tags: c

Here's the code:

```
int my_array[] = {1, 2};
int (*j)[2] = my_array;
```

Compiler says: "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

If I replace the second statement with the following statement, it compiles successfully:

```
int (*j)[2] = &my_array;
```

I can't understand the difference between the two statements because **my_array** and **&my_array** hold the address of the first element in the array.

Comment: `my_array[]` decays to a pointer to `int` (`int *`), but `int (*j)[2]` is a pointer to array of `int`.  Adding the `&` doesn't change the *address*, but it does change the pointer type (to a pointer to an array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember the below rule for arrays in C

**`Array of type T` will be converted to `pointer to type T` in most of the expressions except for `&` and `sizeof` operators.**

```
int my_array[] = {1, 2};
int (*j)[2] = my_array;
```

In the above case, `my_array` is implicitly converted to `pointer to int` (from array of int).

```
int (*j)[2] = &my_array;
```

Where as here, since & operator is involved, it won't let 'my_array' which is `array of int` to get converted to `pointer to int` and returns `pointer to array of int` which is matched to the type of LHS

Answer (score 2):

The difference will be clear if you will introduce a typedef.

For example

```
typedef int T[2];
```

In this case declaration

```
int my_array[] = {1, 2};
```

can be substitute for

```
T my_array = { 1, 2 };
```

Thus you have an object of type T then that to declare a pointer to this object you have to write

```
T *j = &my_array;
```

The size of object my_array is equal to sizeof( T ) that is to `sizeof( int[2] )` that in turn equal to `2 * sizeof( int )`
So if to dereference j you will get object of type T and as the result `sizeof( *j )` is also equal to sizeof( my_array ).

If define `T` like

```
typedef int T;
```

then in this case declaration

```
int my_array[] = {1, 2};
```

will look like

In this case declaration

```
T my_array[] = {1, 2};
```

Thus you have an array of objects of type T then that to declare a pointer to the first element of the array you have to write

```
T *j = my_array;
```

The size of an element of  my_array is equal to sizeof( T ) that is to `sizeof( int )` .
So if to dereference j you will get object of type T and as the result `sizeof( *j )` is also equal to sizeof( int ).

Answer (score 0):

my_array is an array variable of **int type**, and p is an array variable of **int pointer type**. 
They are not the same type variable, so the compiler will complain.
In C, my_arry and &my_array are different types to the compiler, though they have the same value.

- my_array is array variable or can be seen as **int pointer type**.
- &my_array is a seen as an address of my_array, it can be assigned to any pointer type.